# In Anypoint Studio 7 runnig in debug mode application doesn`t stop on toggle breakpoints

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft

I had tried to:

- Restart Anypoin Studio
- Change debug port
- Switch-off firewall

May be someone knows the solution.

Thank you for your help.

---

Helping each other we make our World better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you updated to Studio 7.4.1? It resolves a problem with Studio not stopping at breakpoints: https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/studio/anypoint-studio-7.4-with-4.2-runtime-update-site-1-release-notes#bug-fixes

Comment: Thank you very much. You were right. It works after updating.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is - to upgrade Anypoint Studio(thanks to @aled). I thought that my Studio was already upgraded. Because I`d verified it to available upgrades and had installed all the things. But when I`d opened **Help->About Anypoint Studio** window I`d seen that its version was 7.4.0.

To make my Studio upgraded I`d downloaded new version from the site. Because I could not find the other way.